# Impacts when session is not invalidated on multiple login

Tags: security, session, servlets, web-applications

In web applications, what are the impacts when session is not invalidated when multiple logins happen from different clients (browsers)?

Comment: Your question is too broad: Specify exactly what is contained in your session.

Answer (score 0):

Well that really depends on the kind of web application you're running. If you're running a simple website it could have absolutely no impact besides the fact that people can maintain different instances of logged in (think google and facebook who do this EVERYWHERE). If you're running a MMO game or something where a unique character is to be controlled by one account then it would be impossible to have to multiple instances of the same character. In most cases there is no worry though to having multiple logins. If you have a more specific scenario though that'll be more helpful for giving advice.

Comment: My web application is more specifically a Portal which takes User name and Password to login. Its not a MMO game or something else. Inside my portal there are various functionality offered to end user like recharging his account, checking his account balance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question but generally, the concerns fall into two main categories:

1. **Capacity** : A session is conceptually an object that contains members. One single session object occupies space in your application server's memory. Depending on your server hardware and configuration, you'll eventually run into performance problems where your server has to keep track of hundreds or maybe hundreds thousands of session objects. The capacity issue will be compounded by a poorly written application; Imagine a web application in which each user session initiates a database server connection. Now multiply the number of database connection by the number of active sessions in your web application. Now, your application server may be tuned or built to support millions of active sessions; you might not be able to say the same about your database server. This scenario applies to any other resources that a session object may maintain an active and persistent connection to
2. **Security**: This is largely a matter of application design. A large number of production apps practice selective use of HTTPS whereby the login process is protected with TLS, but the entire user experience is open after the user has logged in. This includes further communication with the application server using the JSESSION_ID. Now, the longer a session id is active, the more prone to hijacking it is. Invalidating a session aggressively is something you'll find in banking apps and the likes. There's no reason why a sane banking application will keep your banking session alive longer than 10 minutes idle